# How to fetch Hibernate object and map it to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I have a problem. When I'm trying to get `JSON` object of `Employee` I can't see one very important field (`company`). For example, I need to get object like this:

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "company": {
        "name": "Microsoft",
        "id": 4
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

But instead I'm getting an object without a company (WRONG!):

```
{
    "name": "Bill",
    "id": 2
}
```

At the same time I want to get json object of Company:

```
{
    "name": "Microsoft",
    "employees": [
        {
            "name": "Jack",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Frank",
            "id": 3
        }
    ],
    "id": 4
}
```

Company object is OK. It's look perfect when I'm getting it. The problem is in Employee object.

Here is my entity classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
```

And my Employee class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    @Column
    String name;

    @ManyToOne()
    @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Company company;
```

I think the probjem is in @Json[SomeCondition] annotation. Is anybody can help me to fix the code. I need to get Employee object with companym like this:

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "company": {
        "name": "Microsoft",
        "id": 4
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

UPD:

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Collection<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employeeService.getEmployees();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.PUT},
                    produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return employeeService.getEmployee(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json",
                    headers = "content-type=application/json")
    public String addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json",
                    headers = "content-type=application/json")
    public String updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/employee/" + employee.getId();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
        return "redirect:/employee";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I mistaken with @JsonManagedReference annotation using.

Comment: please let us know what is the solution of that problem, i am also facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

It is problem of EAGER and LAZY fetching in hibernate. Be carefull about both concept. Read about it before implements it.
add fetch=FetchType.EAGER when you define relation in Company Class.

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
     @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JsonManagedReference
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
```